# Grouping by unique IDs, applying a function, and updating a certain column for next groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, updating

I have a data frame looking like this:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': ['m1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3'],
   ...:                     'name':['peter', 'mike', 'jeff', 'john', 'alex', 'joe', 'jeff', 'peter', 'alex', 'peter', '
   ...: joe', 'tom' ],
   ...:                     'rank': [2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2],
   ...:                     'rating': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    match_id    name    rank  rating
0          m1  peter     2     100
1          m1   mike     3     100
2          m1   jeff     1     100
3          m1   john     4     100
4          m2   alex     3     100
5          m2    joe     1     100
6          m2   jeff     2     100
7          m2  peter     4     100
8          m3   alex     4     100
9          m3  peter     3     100
10         m3    joe     1     100
11         m3    tom     2     100
```

It is about three matches with unique "match_id"s, the participants' names, their rank at the end of the match, and a default rating score manually set to 100 for the whole data frame.

I want to group the data based on "match_id"s and run a function for each match separately, but the function's output should be used for updating a column for next matches.

I want to use a function that calculates the players updated ratings after each match and puts it in a new column named "updated_rating". The function that I tired looks like this for the first match:

```py
df = df.loc[df['match_id'] == 'm1']
N = len(df)
df['win_prob'] = 0.0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if i != j:
            df['S'] = (N - df['rank']) / ((N*(N-1))/2)
            df['win_prob'][i] += (1 / (1 + (10 ** ((df['rating'][i] - df['rating'][j])/400))))
            df['normalized_win_prob'] = df['win_prob']/(N*(N-1)/2)
            df['updated_rating'] = round(df['rating'] + (20 * (df['S'] - df['normalized_win_prob'])), 1)
```

This will do the trick for the first match and calculates the updated ratings as well as the probability of winning for each player based on their original ratings. However, I could not extend this to account for the following matches.

Since some players reappeared in the next matches, I want to update their ratings (based on calculated "updated_rating" column in the previous phase) and let the function do the job for the second match and for the third match after that.

So, for example, the output **after the calculations for the first match** would look like this:

```py
match_id name rank rating  win_prob    S    normalized_win_prob  updated_rating
0   m1  peter   2   100     1.5     0.333333          0.25            101.7
1   m1  mike    3   100     1.5     0.166667          0.25             98.3
2   m1  jeff    1   100     1.5     0.500000          0.25            105.0
3   m1  john    4   100     1.5     0.000000          0.25             95.0
```

Any ideas on how to do this in an efficient way? 
My original data frame is way larger than this sample data frame, so my solution needs to be efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't generate the results you posted for the first match. Could you make them consistent here? Also, what do you expect after second match?

Comment: @NeilZ Edited. 'jeff' and 'peter' also appeared in match 2, so I want their "rating" for match 2 to be equal to their "updated_rating" calculated in match 1. So "jeff"s rating in row 6 should be updated to 105, and "peter"s rating in row 7 should be updated to 101.7. "Peter" also appeared in match 3, so his "rating" for match 3 should also be updated to 101.7, but it should be updated again after applying the function to match 2 (since he participated in match 2 as well). The data is sorted by date, so the rating of each player will be updated after each match. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here will my solution. Since your algorithm has to loop through the match_ids one by one, so we need the `for-loop` on grouped data first. Then to compute the `win_prob`, you have to go through each row and compute its related probability to win against other rows in the same match. It's not pretty. Can't think of a better way though :(

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': ['m1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm2', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm3', 'm4', 'm4', 'm4', 'm4'],
                   'name':['peter', 'mike', 'jeff', 'john', 'alex', 'joe', 'jeff', 'peter', 'alex', 'peter', 'joe', 'tom', 'mike', 'john', 'tom', 'peter'],
                   'rank': [2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2],
                   'rating': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]})

# Pre-compute variables that don't depend on ratings
df['N'] = df.groupby('match_id')['name'].transform('count')
df['total_comb'] = ((df['N']*(df['N']-1))/2)
df['S'] = (df['N'] - df['rank']) / df['total_comb']

# Initialize win_prob and updated_rating
df['win_prob'] = np.zeros(len(df))
df['updated_rating'] = df['rating']
df['prev_rating'] = df['rating']

grouped = df.groupby('match_id', sort=True)

dfa = pd.DataFrame() #Final results will be stored here
last_names = []
#Loop through the match_ids from m1 to m2, m3. Note you can sort them when use 'groupby'
for name, dfg in grouped:
    dfm = dfg.copy()
    # Update the 'updated_rating' coming from last match_id
    if len(last_names) > 0:
        dfm.drop(columns=['updated_rating'], inplace=True)
        df_last = dfa.loc[dfa['match_id'].isin(last_names),['name', 'updated_rating']]
        df_last.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'], keep='last', inplace=True)
        dfm = dfm.merge(df_last, left_on='name', right_on='name', how='left')
        dfm['prev_rating'] = np.where(np.isnan(dfm['updated_rating']), dfm['rating'], dfm['updated_rating'])

    # Compute current 'updated_rating'
    win_prob = []
    for index, row in dfm.iterrows():
        prob = np.sum(1.0/(1+10**((row['prev_rating'] - dfm['prev_rating'])/400)))-0.5 #subtract 0.5 to account for self
        win_prob.append(prob)

    dfm['win_prob'] = win_prob
    dfm['normalized_win_prob'] = dfm['win_prob']/dfm['total_comb']
    dfm['updated_rating'] = round(dfm['prev_rating'] + (20 * (dfm['S'] - dfm['normalized_win_prob'])), 1)
    last_names.append(name)
    dfa = pd.concat([dfa, dfm], sort=True)

dfa
```

The output:

```
N       S         match_id  name    normalized_win_prob prev_rating   rank  rating  total_comb  updated_rating  win_prob
4   0.333333333     m1      peter   0.25                    100         2   100     6               101.7       1.5
4   0.166666667     m1      mike    0.25                    100         3   100     6               98.3        1.5
4   0.5             m1      jeff    0.25                    100         1   100     6               105         1.5
4   0               m1      john    0.25                    100         4   100     6               95          1.5
4   0.166666667     m2      alex    0.251606926             100         3   100     6               98.3        1.509641559
4   0.5             m2      joe     0.251606926             100         1   100     6               105         1.509641559
4   0.333333333     m2      jeff    0.24681015              105         2   100     6               106.7       1.480860898
4   0               m2      peter   0.249975997             101.7       4   100     6               96.7        1.499855985
4   0               m3      alex    0.251630798             98.3        4   100     6               93.3        1.509784788
4   0.166666667     m3      peter   0.253165649             96.7        3   100     6               95          1.518993896
4   0.5             m3      joe     0.245203608             105         1   100     6               110.1       1.47122165
4   0.333333333     m3      tom     0.249999944             100         2   100     6               101.7       1.499999666
4   0.5             m4      mike    0.249232493             98.3        1   100     6               103.3       1.495394959
4   0.166666667     m4      john    0.252398303             95          3   100     6               93.3        1.514389819
4   0               m4      tom     0.2459709               101.7       4   100     6               96.8        1.475825403
4   0.333333333     m4      peter   0.252398303             95          2   100     6               96.6        1.514389819
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Only one issue, at the beginning of each match, I need to know the most recent rating of each player to compare the true rankings with ranking by sorting pre-match ratings to see if the order is the same (whether players with generally higher ratings get better rankings or not). Is there any way to set the pre-match "rating"s to be the "updated_rating" from the previous matches? For example, on match 2, can we set "rating" column of Peter to be 101.7 (his "updated_rating" from match 1)? and on match 3, to be 96.7 (his "updated_rating" from match 2)

Comment: @Arde sure you can, just create a new column, e.g. 'pre-rating', and set it to 'updated_rating', right before the comment line:
# Compute current 'updated_rating'.

The "if last_name is not None:" block is to get the updated ratings from last match. Just assign them to the new column.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Just for the record, I ran it on a subset of my data (10000 rows) and it gave the answers within a minute, so hopefully, it works fine on my whole data as well.

Comment: It's unlikely to be very fast, since your algo requires to loop through each match id one by one, and inside each loop, you need to iterate over the rows to compute the updated probabilities. Unless you can decompose the algo to more independent parts, like the `S`.

Comment: I just found an issue in the code, imagine there is a fourth match "m4" where "Mike" who was present only in the first match "m1" is competing against three other people. In this case, the code resets Mike's current rating to 100 (while it should be equal to 98.3 based on the results of the first match "m1" and his updated_rating). Do you have any possible solution or modification for this issue?

Comment: @Arde that's a good catch, I made the change, added a `prev_rating` column so it's easier to check. and added `m4` as test, could you try again?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a ton